# Check if the array can be sorted with a single swap of 2 elements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to write a function that will check if the array can be sorted with a single swap of the values in the array.

For example: `array(1,3,5,3,7)` must return `true`, but `array(1,3,5,3,4)` must return `false`.

I tried the following code below, but I'm stuck with it:

```
$noOfIterations = 0;

for($x = 0; $x < count($a)-2; $x++) {

    if($a[$x] > $a[$x+1]) {
        $noOfIterations ++;
    }

}

return $noOfIterations >1; 

// The below solution helped as well.

//$arr = [1, 3, 5, 3, 7];  //[1, 3, 5, 3, 4]
$arr = [1, 3, 5, 3, 4];
$sortedArr = $arr;
sort($sortedArr);
print_r(array_intersect_assoc($arr,$sortedArr));
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Actually I did but I seem to have lost the code.
what I was trying was 
    $noOfIterations =0;
    for($x=0; $x < count($a)-2; $x++){
     if($a[$x]>$a[$x+1]){
        $noOfIterations ++;
    }
}
return  $noOfIterations >1;

Comment: Then try again, maybe this time you're lucky, otherwise post your new attempt here!

Comment: pick us all up some coffee and donuts, what're you having @Rizier123 ?

Comment: @Rizier123 see my second code piece courtesy Mark Baker, Your solution was good with helpful explanation, Mark's solution was short. I thank both of you guys for your great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the sort, then compare the original array with the sorted array using [array_intersect_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php).... if the difference is more than two elements, then the answer is 'no'

Comment: Did you tried your solution? http://3v4l.org/SQDGS *if the difference is more than two elements, then the answer is 'no'* But OP expect for this the output to be true.

Comment: I hadn't tried it, but I was thinking something more like `$data = array(1,3,5,3,7);

function goCompare($data) {
    $data2 = $data;
    sort($data2);
    $result = array_intersect_assoc($data, $data2);
    return !(count($data) - count($result) > 2);
}
if (goCompare($data)) {
    echo 'single swap';
} else {
    echo 'multiple swaps';
}
`

Comment: I think ^ that comes closer to what OP wants

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for this but when you say difference is more than three elements, how come I will know this if the difference is more than 2 elements ? Does it mean that I will have to do count on original array and then the result array and then subtract?

Comment: The code I've quoted in my previous comment should tell you exactly.... and it's difference is more than 2 elements, not more than 3 elements.... that's what the counts in the return statement do

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

(Here I first make a copy of the original array to then [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) it. After this I loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and look how many position has changed. With [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) I sort the elements out where no position has changed. Then you can simply check if 2 or more position has changed and print either FALSE or TRUE)

```
<?php

    $arr = [1, 3, 5, 3, 7];  //[1, 3, 5, 3, 4]
    $sortedArr = $arr;
    sort($sortedArr);

    $filtered = array_filter(
        array_map(function($v1, $v2){
            return ($v1 == $v2 ?FALSE:TRUE);
        }, $arr, $sortedArr)
    );

    var_dump(count($filtered) > 2 ? FALSE : TRUE);

?>
```

output:

```
TRUE  //FALSE
```

Comment: Hi Rizier, thanks I am trying to work on your solution but it fails on both arrays.

Comment: Hi Rizier I am running it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and this is the code that I am running.
    //$arr = array(1, 3, 5, 3, 7);  
    $arr = array(1, 3, 5, 3, 4);
    $sortedArr = $arr;
    sort($sortedArr);
    $filtered = array_filter(
        array_map(function($v1, $v2){
            return ($v1 == $v2 ?FALSE:TRUE);
        }, $arr, $sortedArr)
    );

    var_dump(count($filtered) >= 2 ? FALSE : TRUE);

Comment: @WajidAbbasi forgot to remove the equal sign in the var_dump call! Just remove it and the code works fine!

Comment: Ahh thanks :) by the way can you please shed a light on the array_filter and array_map and what logic did you use to solve this problem ?

Comment: @WajidAbbasi Did you read my explanation? I just go through both arrays and if the position is the same I return FALSE and if it changed TRUE. With array_filter I simply filter the ones out which didn't changed

Comment: You should accept this answer @WajidAbbasi as it is the most correct and has a detailed explanation.

Comment: Sorry Jay Blanchard :) Just came after a long layoff to stackoverflow :).

Comment: Superb work.  I would like to say , OP should appreciate the efforts and accept this answer.....

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna do it with a loop, you can do it with a double loop comparing each value to one another. You need to get a little creative with the comparing. From what I see, your code succeeds on the first array but fails on the second. It fails on the second one because you are only checking 2 adjacent entries and 3 is always less than 4. Or you can keep track of the largest number and count how many numbers are less than that value past it. Also make sure to add to the count if you encounter another bigger value. Hope all this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

What if array is sorted and no swap is needed?

It might help if I knew Why.

Try this, it works for your two example arrays.

```
function swap($array){
  $prev = 0;
  $count = 0;
  foreach($array as $val){
    if($val < $prev){
       $count++;
    }
    else{
      $prev = $val;
    }
  }
  if($count < 2){return(true);}else{return(false);}
}
```

Comment: If the array is sorted and no swap is needed then it should return true. But thanks for your help and giving me an insight. I feel that I need to brush up on my skills once again that I learnt during my university times.

Answer (score 0):

My answer in php.

```
function oneSwap($A){

  $count=count($A);
  $swaps=0;
  $curr_max = 0;
  $res = false;
  for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    if(isset($A[$i+1])){
      if(($A[$i] >= $A[$i + 1]) && $curr_max >= $A[$i+1]){
        $swaps++;
      }

      if($A[$i] >= $A[$i +1]){
          $curr_max = $A[$i];
      }
    }

  }

  if(($swaps == 1) || ($swaps == 0 && $curr_max ==0)){
    $res = true;
    echo $res;
  } 
} 

oneSwap([3,1,2,8]);
oneSwap([1,2,3]);
oneSwap([1,5,3,3,7]);
oneSwap([3,2,1,8]);
oneSwap([2,1,1,2]);
```